# My app won't switch from my Main to my Dashboard activities. Is the issue in my my intent or manifest?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I created a splash screen and set an intent for it to switch to my DashboardActivity after it finishes its animation. However, it won't switch over to the DashboardActivity when I ran it on my device. The splash screen finished playing and then the app ended abrubtly. I have a hunch that the issue is in the intent or in the manifest but I am not sure.

Here is my code:

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Brik"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_SCREEN = 4000;

    // Variables
    Animation logoAnim;
    ImageView logo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Animation
        logoAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.logo_anim);

        // Hooks
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);

        // Set Animation to Image
        logo.setAnimation(logoAnim);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_SCREEN);

    }
}
```

EDIT

***DashboardActivity***

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

            //all the logic of the onCreate will be put after this comment

            //we now initialize the sdk
            VoxeetSDK.initialize("grB4NiWlMEvzpaLbBKBmVw==", "ap6TnDQpnFUEPlIgrN3ir3hoL2NLrCLHLHd1s_YjYW0=");

            //adding the user_name, login and logout views related to the open/close and conference flow
            add(views, R.id.login);
            add(views, R.id.logout);

            add(buttonsNotLoggedIn, R.id.login);
            add(buttonsNotLoggedIn, R.id.user_name);

            add(buttonsInConference, R.id.logout);

            add(buttonsNotInConference, R.id.logout);

            // Set a random user name
            String[] avengersNames = {
                    "Thor",
                    "Cap",
                    "Tony Stark",
                    "Black Panther",
                    "Black Widow",
                    "Hulk",
                    "Spider-Man",
            };
            Random r = new Random();
            user_name.setText(avengersNames[r.nextInt(avengersNames.length)]);

            // Add the join button and enable it only when not in a conference
            add(views, R.id.join);
            add(buttonsNotInConference, R.id.join);

            // Set a default conference name
            conference_name.setText("Avengers meeting");

            // Add the leave button and enable it only while in a conference
            add(views, R.id.leave);
            add(buttonsInConference, R.id.leave);

        }
```

Comment: Everything looks fine. The issue might be caused by your DashboardActivity. Can you please post the error logs.

Comment: @AlphaOne I actually had no errors. I can post my DashboardActivity.

Comment: I think the problem is not for intent passing or AndroidManifest. I guess the problem is in Butterknife.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your manifest.xml file.
Your activity is in another activity

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Brik"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Change this to:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Brik"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```